# Equation with variable within an integral sign

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This seems as a very easy equation but I am having a hard time solving it. I need to solve for $\beta(t)$ . $q_i(t)$'s are given. (Extra fact : $\int q_i(t)^2dt=L_i$ where $L_i$'s are constants)

Have to minimize the cost fucntion $$C=\sum_i\left(\int q_i(t)(q_i(t)-\beta(t))dt\right)^2$$

Doing $\frac{dC}{d\beta(t)}=0$ I have reduced it to $$\frac{\beta}{\beta^{\prime}}\sum_i \left(q_i(t)L_i-q_i(t)\int q_i(s)\beta(s)ds\right)=0$$

Comment: There's something wrong with the parentheses I think: The $dt$ and $\int$ are not in the same bracket...
Do you mean $C=\sum_i\left(\int q_i(t)(q_i(t)-\beta(t)) dt\right)^2$ or $C=\sum_i\int\left(q_i(t)(q_i(t)-\beta(t)) \right)^2dt$ or ...?

Comment: @KevinDietrich Silly me!